# How to filter entities by their parents in ManyToOne side in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I use Google App Engine. When I try to do a JPA query like this:

```
SELECT p FROM Participant p 
WHERE p.party.id = :partyKey AND p.name=:participantName
```

I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: 
SELECT FROM Participant p WHERE p.party.id = :partyKey AND p.name=:participantName: 
Can only reference properties of a sub-object if the sub-object is embedded.
```

I gave the key of the Party object as a parameter to the "partyKey" named parameter.

The model is like this: Party has multiple Participants.

I want to query a participant based on the party and the name of the participant. I just can't figure out how to filter using the party. What options do I have?

I've also tried the following query:

```
SELECT FROM Participant p 
WHERE p.party = :party AND p.name=:participantName
```

but it results in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: 
SELECT FROM Participant p WHERE p.party = :party AND p.name=:participantName: 
Key of parameter value does not have a parent.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do ancestor queries by declaring a parent-pk field. You can then filter the child object using that field. Check the part about "parent-pk" in [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html#Using_Transactions) (and be **sure** to read [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/6de4dfe44f0d0f11/591953391921c57d?#591953391921c57d)).

**Update:** For JPA, it seems you would declare it like this:

```
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.parent-pk")
private Long parentId;
```

You might also want to read the [Querying with Key parameters](http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2010/01/querying-with-key-parameters.html) blog post.

Comment: I'm using JPA and that documentation is for JDO. How exactly do I declare a parent-pk field?

Comment: @palto: Yes, the documentation is for JDO but this applies to JPA too. And I agree, the JPA documentation of GAE sucks big time (it's like Google doesn't want you to use JPA)...