# How to filter entities by their parents in Many-To-One in AppEngine using JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have two classes: `Parent` and `Child`. Parent has a List of Child objects and child object has a reference to it's parent using `@Persistent (mappedBy = "parent")`.

How can I filter child objects by it's parents attributes?
I have tried `query.setFilter("parent.key == " + parentKey);` But that didn't work. Do I have to map parent's attribute to child somehow?

I'm pretty much asking the same as here [How to filter entities by their parents in ManyToOne side in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032406/how-to-filter-entities-by-their-parents-in-manytoone-side-in-google-app-engine) but using JDO not JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. This would require a join, which the App Engine datastore does not support. Instead, either fetch all the parents that match the parent criteria, then perform a separate query on each result for its children, or denormalize, and add the properties you care about to the child entity.

Comment: Thanks for the answe! But then why does the child have an attribute that links to it's parent if it can't be used to fetch the parent itself?

Comment: @Rob It can be used to fetch the parent - it just can't be used to refer to a parent's properties in a query. If all you want to do is query for all children with a given parent, that's an ancestor query, which isn't supported in JDO - only in the low level API, documented here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html. IF you have a choice of database frameworks, I'd strongly recommend switching to Objectify, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try Objectify and then choose if I will recode my database bridges.